# Setting env variable from Perl and using in Makefile

Tags: bash, perl, unix, makefile

I'm trying to set env variable from Perl script and using it inside Makefile doesn't work. While dumping ENV hash tree shows variable successfully set.

Makefile code

```
list_gen: $(TESTBENCH_PATH)/blocks/soc_tb/global/default 
    perl list_gen.pl; \
    $(MAKE) $(RECITAL_PATH)/catalog/catalog.xml 

    @ touch $@


# Generates catalog.xml from .xmls of VIPs
$(RECITAL_PATH)/catalog/catalog.xml: $(VIP_XMLs) 
    @echo "#  generating catalog.xml " ;                                \
    echo "vip list is $(VIP_LIST)" ;                                \
    rpfCatalog --add $(VIP_XMLs);                       \
    for vip in $(VIP_LIST);                                         \
    do                                  \
       rpfCatalog --add $$TESTBENCH_PATH/common_blocks/$$vip/global/default.xml; \
    done
```

Perl Script code

```
$ENV{"VIP_LIST"} = $vip_exists;
```

Comment: And how does the perl script invoke make?

Comment: Are you trying to use perl script to set an environment variable and use it later? A perl script runs in a sub-shell; it doesn't carry it's value into parent shell.

Comment: perl script isn't invoking make. after execution of perl script .. make is recursively called so that env. variable update is visible to make

Comment: Changes in %ENV in Perl don't propagate to the parent process. You can `print` the value and capture it to a make variable, though.

Comment: @choroba : Okay .. so how can variable value available to makefile ?

Comment: You have to export the variable globally to the OS level and fetch the same in the makefile

Comment: @Karan Shah: Could you guide me how it can be done in this case .. you mean to say using export inside system in perl

Comment: Added it as an answer, please check if it works

Comment: You are misunderstanding how environment variables are used.  The environment block is *copied* from parent to child.  It is not shared, there is only an export, there is no "import".  You have to set the variable in the **parent**, setting it in a child will only affect the child and its children.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any elegant way to update environment of **make** by running any external command (like perl script) from it. Because even a direct way wouldn't work.

```
/home/user> cat makefile
NUM=100

first:
        NUM=200
        echo $(NUM)    
second:
        NUM=200; echo $(NUM)    
third:
        NUM=200; \
        echo $(NUM);

/home/user> make first
NUM=200
echo 100
100

/home/user> make second
NUM=200; echo 100
100

/home/user> make third
NUM=200; \
echo 100;
100
```

---

If you are only looking for a perl script to modify it's parent's environment, something like this works (in a very limited way):

```
/home/user> cat change_env.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "NUM=100\n";

/home/user> NUM=1
/home/user> echo $NUM
1
/home/user> eval $(./change_env.pl)
/home/user> echo $NUM
100
```

---

Coming to original your question, .. can't you call make after making the changes to your shell environment?

Comment: thanks but it's not i'm looking for. I need env. variable to be updated inside makefile from perl script(which was called from makefile)

Comment: I have thought that make sense modification in some(x) file then it will run perl script to update env. variable then make uses updated variable but now it seems i have to read (X file) in make and update variable. Do you have any better suggestion ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
VIP_LIST=$(perl my.pl)
```

Would save the output of the script in the variable of the parent shell.

HTH
Georg

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your Perl script, do it like $(./myperlscript.pl) on the prompt. What you need to do is

```
$ENV{VIP_LIST} = $vip_exists;
```

Drop the quotes

Comment: Are you trying to run the perl interpreter in the current shell (by prefixing the shell script with a dot)?

Comment: yes, I am. This will export it in the same process.

Comment: @KaranShah, I am not the downvoter, but I guess it was probably downvoted because your intent is not clear.